# How to send a low heart rate notification to an iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I have an arduino which generates a simulated heart rate.I am able to connect to the iPhone using BLE and save the heart rate into the health vault.

For test purpose I want to send low heart rate notification to the iPhone health vault whenever the heart rate falls below a certain level. However, the apple documents mentions that i cannot write to the low heart rate notification. If so, how is iwatch able to write to the iPhone health vault for low heart rates?
Extract from apple document

```
The low heart rate samples are read-only. Use this identifier to request permission to read these samples; however, you can’t request authorization to share them, and you can’t save new low heart rate events to the HealthKit store.
```

Please recommend some steps to achieve the above?

Comment: I would imagine that you just send a low value, Apple determines if it is low or not

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am also building an iOS app which handles the heart rate received from the arduino and based on certain logic levels decide when to push that value into the lowheartrate sample in the health vault. But i dont know how to achieve that. I can generate a notification but that event wont get registered by Apple unless the user configures it separately within the health vault

Answer (score 0):

Often time Apple made applications can get some special privileges using undocumented API or Info.plist keys.  Apple is allowing itself to use those undocumented/restricted features for its own products (obviously) but due to either risk of abuse, or because the API is not yet in a clean-enough state for them, they do not want developers to use those features.

So it is quite possible that in this case there is no proper way for you to achieve this exact behaviour.

---

As @Scriptable mentioned, maybe just sending low values would be enough for their library to decide if a notification should be sent.

Comment: thank you @ekscrypto for your response.
How will i be able to add my arduino as a source for updating low heart rate notifications data to health vault if there is no obvious route?

Comment: If you have an Apple Developer Account, you can request a technical support, they will provide code level support to help you achieve your results.  Whether what you are trying to do will fit within the support or not is up to them however.  For more information head over to https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/